# xamarin master page bind content page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, cross-platform

I'm using xamarin cross-platform.
I want to add  same the "floating menu item" in the every .xaml page.(home/logout/view/ account)

I have added below master page.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ABCAPP.Views.MasterDetailPage1"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:ABCAPP.Views">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:MasterDetailPage1Master x:Name="MasterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MasterDetailPage1Detail>

                    <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
                         <!--top controls--> 
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                         <!--middle controls--> 
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">

                            <Button Text="A" FontAttributes="Bold"  BackgroundColor="MediumSlateBlue" BorderRadius="50" TextColor="White"></Button>
                            <Button Text="B" FontAttributes="Bold"  BackgroundColor="MediumSlateBlue"  TextColor="White"></Button>


                         <!--bottom controls--> 
                    </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </pages:MasterDetailPage1Detail>
            </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

How do I add this layout to my other .xaml Content Pages ?

This is my Content Pages

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ABCAPP.Views.Confirmed">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15" BackgroundColor="Orange">
                <Label Text="Thank you!" FontSize="50" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"   />
                <Label Text=" confirmed." FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
                <Label x:Name="lblMsg" TextColor="Red"   IsVisible="False" ></Label>
                <Button Text="ADD " Clicked="NewAttend_Clicked" FontAttributes="Bold"  BackgroundColor="MediumSlateBlue" BorderRadius="5"  TextColor="White"></Button>

                <Button Text="RETURN " Clicked="List_Clicked" FontAttributes="Bold"  BackgroundColor="MediumSlateBlue"  BorderRadius="5" TextColor="White"></Button>
                <Image Source="drawable/icon"  ></Image>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: create your own BasePage class that inherits from ContentPage and that includes your menu.  Then have all of your pages inherit from this BasePage.

Comment: Can you please give some example.. I'm new for apps